# Networking configuring problem with ip address

Tags: networking

I have been having some trouble trying to connect to the ethernet. Well, the thing is, my ethernet requires IP configuration. I have tried configuring it using GUI and also terminal but   no success. Please help.

These are the results to my ifconfig command:

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:92:4a:2a:6d:ba  
          inet addr:172.46.16.145  Bcast:172.46.16.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d9400000-d9420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3704 (3.7 KB)  TX bytes:3704 (3.7 KB)
```

Comment: You appear to be connected to a subnet 172.46.16.0/24. There must at least be a DHCP server on the network that handed you this address (unless you specified that yourself as a static address). What is the output of `ip route`?

Comment: In the GUI, what did you specify for address, netmask, gateway and DNS nameservers? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: In the GUI for address 172.16.46.145, netmask 255.255.240.0 , gateway 172.16.46.100, DNS-nameserver 8.8.8.8